# Retrieve Adwords MCC / Manager Account ID using adwords API

Tags: google-ads-api

How do I get the adwords MCC / Manager Account ID using the Google Adwords API. I have gone through the documentation but was unable to find it.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation it states

> ClientCustomerId will be required for all requests except for
>   CustomerService.get

The details of the CustomerService.get request can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201605/CustomerService#get)